# "," at the end of a single element in a object in javascript is illegal?

Tags: javascript

I wonder why putting a comma at the end of a single element is legal in a JavaScript array:

```
var array = [
    'foo', // no error in IDE
]
```

while putting it at the end of a single element in an object is illegal (at least my IDE - WebStorm - is flagging about an error):

```
var object = {
    'foo': 'bar', // error in IDE
}
```

Is this really illegal in JavaScript?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the ECMAScript 5 specification it is legal:

```
ObjectLiteral : 
    { } 
    { PropertyNameAndValueList } 
    { PropertyNameAndValueList , }
```

It was illegal in ECMAScript 3.

```
ObjectLiteral : 
    { } 
    { PropertyNameAndValueList }
```

I believe it was made legal to make things like this doable.

```
function getItems() {
    return {
        one : 1,
        two : 2,
        three : 3,
        //four : 4,
    };
}
```

Instead of this:

```
function getItems() {
    return {
        one : 1,
        two : 2,
        three : 3//,
        //four : 4,
    };
}
```

Saving some of the programmers time.

Comment: +1 for going to the spec.  Now, why they would add that second line to make this construction legal confounds me.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to have a link to where it says that in the spec would you?

Comment: @zzzzBov - See section **11.1.5 Object Initialiser**: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what ChaosPandion mentioned, there's an important difference between a `,` at the end of an object and an array. Empty commas in an array (technically called *elisions*) insert `undefined` elements at the corresponding position; this increases the length of the array but the values are `undefined`.

**Edit:** Thanks to ChaosPandion and CMS for pointing out the error. I just reread the specs and indeed a single trailing comma *does not* increase the length, however any additional trailing commas or any commas in the middle of an array *will* increase the length.

For example, `[ 1,2,, ]` is an array of length 3 and the same as `[ 1, 2, undefined ]`. Similarly, `[ 1,,,2 ]` is an array of length 4 and the same as `[ 1, undefined, undefined, 2 ]`.

<del>Strangely enough, when it comes to this "feature" of JavaScript, IE behaves correctly with a trailing comma in an array (it counts the extra element) while Firefox ignores the last undefined element.</del>

Comment: A small mistake, the syntax allows one trailing comma so to make an array of length three you would have to write this: `[ 1,2,, ]`

Comment: See previous comment. But +1 for talking about arrays and trailing commas.

Comment: @casablanca, a trailing comma in `ArrayInitializer` shouldn't insert `undefined` element, this was misunderstood by some implementers of ES3, now in ES5 this was clarified: From ES5 [Annex D](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Annex_D) "Edition 5 clarifies the fact that a trailing comma at the end of an `ArrayInitializer` does not add to the length of the array. This is not a semantic change from Edition 3 but some implementations may have previously misinterpreted this."

Comment: ... so, IE <=8 (JScript <= 5.8 more precisely) misbehaves with trailing commas on `ArrayInitializer` -they should be ignored-, but it has the right ES3 behavior for `ObjectLiterals` as @ChaosPandion mentions on his answer, a trailing comma isn't valid for a ES3 implementation (IE correctly throws `SyntaxError` e.g. `({a:0,})`), thing that other ES3 implementations tolerate (obviously as a non-standard ES3 syntax extension).

Comment: @ChaosPandion, @CMS: Thanks, I somehow misunderstood the grammar. Indeed the production says `ElementList , Elision_opt` so the comma in the rule itself is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox tolerates it, most other sane browsers do so to. Do I still need to mention IE chokes on it?

Anyway, simply ensure there are no commas at the end of arrays/objects. While languages like PHP and - depending on the implementation - JavaScript are fine with it, it is extremely ugly - you also wouldn't leave a string at the end of a file unclosed just because the parser *could* consider EOF as a valid string end.

Comment: Do you think it's a mistake that C enforces a semi-colon on the final line of a file? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are using IE.

Comment: Using IE (at least IE<9) at all should be made illegal, too. :>